# Cannot find JSP to Servlet(.java) translated file in Tomcat work folder (intellij)

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

After I have made and executed a .jsp file on Web, I can't still find .java translated file in any folder.
My project folder path (I guess) is :

C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\IdeaProjects

And Tomcat Home folder is :
C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\IdeaProjects\tools\apache-tomcat-9.0.56-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.56

I searched every folder there for _jsp.java servlet file to no avail.

Am I searching a wrong place?

Comment: If you are using default setting for Tomcat in IntelliJ and use it to deploy artefacts you can try to find translated files under  Intelij application cache folder. On Ubuntu it will be under ~/.cache/JetBrains/IntelliJIdea2021.3/
On Windows search for JetBrains .

Comment: You mean C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.1 this directory? I can't find it here, either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For window it shall be  C:\Users\youruser\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IdeaIversion\tomcat if you have "Tomcat and TomEE"  plugin , not sure if it is available on your IntelliJ

if you are on community IntelliJ with "Smart Tomcat" plugin the work directory will be something like this - C:\Users\username.SmartTomcat\untitled\untitled\work\Catalina\localhost\untitled, untitled is a project name

At least it is what I see on my Windows box.